# Mocking a File using Mockito and PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am writing a `JUnit` test case for a method that uses `FileWriter` to create a file but the file physically doesn't exist. I am using `PowerMockito` to mock the `File` Object without creating a real file. My test passes but it still creates a file by the name of `Mock for file,hashCode` in the context root of the project. Is there a way to avoid creating this file? There are some similar questions but not very clear why this is happening.So, while debugging I found out that when the code reaches to `new FileWriter` the file is created.

Thanks,

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testCreateCSVFile() throws Exception {
    File mockFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockFile);
    rest of the test...
}
```

Method under test:

```
public void createCSVFile(List<IUiIntegrationDto> intgList, String fileName) throws Exception { 
     FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
     rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Pass the writer to the method, not the name.

Comment: It worked. I am passing FileWriter now instead of the name and it doesn't create the file anymore. Thanks.

Comment: And just for the record: if you would be using dependency injection to and **provide** a file writer object to your class under test, you wouldn't need to turn to PowerMock. One core point of writing testable code is to be careful about using **new** statements in your production code (see https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 for details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mocking the wrong field. you need to mock `FileWriter` - this is the one that does the actual file writting

Comment: And he might as well just use `Writer` anyway.

Comment: I mocked FileWriter instead now it creates a file by the name of "Mock for FileWriter, hashCode".

Comment: It's working now as desired. I had to pass the FileWriter not the name of the file in the method and that took care of it.